# reading the date from sqlite in android

Tags: android-sqlite

I am storing some date in sqlite and when I try to retrieve data, it is returning null.

```
private ArrayList<String> file_list = new ArrayList<>();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         ArrayList<String> _list = db.get_file
              (String.valueOf(myFiles.get(position).getId()), file_list);
         Log.e("TAG","_list " + _list);

         case R.id.get_file:
            boolean save_file = db.add_file(String.valueOf(myFiles.get(position).getId()),
                                 file_list);
                    if (save_file){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "saved failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

    public ArrayList<String> get_file(String id, ArrayList<String> arrayList){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_FILE + " FROM "
            +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return arrayList;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

 public TrackGroupArray read_tga_file(String id, TrackGroupArray tga)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TGA_FILE + " FROM "
                +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return tga;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
  

   TrackGroupArray read_tga = db.read_tga_file(String.valueOf(myFiles.get(position).getId()),
                    trackGroupArray);
```

Every time I save a file, it is saved successfully, I have checked in the db and the file is there. But when I want to retrieve it, `Log.e("TAG","_list " + _list);` returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **get_File** method, even if there is a row and the **moveToFirst** succeeds, will always return null as in the event that a row is located/selected you do nothing other than return an un-instantiated arrayList.

You need to

- **a) instantiate the arrayList** (otherwise it will be null) and then
- **b) add elements to the arrayList** for each row that exists if any.

So something like :-

```
   @SuppressLint("Range")
   public ArrayList<String> get_file(String id, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_FILE + " FROM "
              + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + _ID + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

      ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>(); //<<<<< A instantiate the ArrayList<String>
      
      /* Loop through the returned row(s) if any */
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         /* for each iteration add an element to rv (the ArrayList) */
         rv.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_FILE)));
      }
      cursor.close(); //<<<<< should ALWAYS close Cursors when done with them
      return rv; // return the arraylist
   }
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mike it worked. If you don't mind, I have another method `read_tga_file` in db, which is returning null. I tried to apply the above logic but it is still returning null. The data is there in db and I can not access it.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: @aawasi from the code, bar the column name, they are the same, thus then either the id does not match or the TrackGroupArray passed is null.