# unable to access data from sqlite android

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to get the data from the sqlite android but I am getting null. I have saved the data successfully in the db but I can not access it. Here is my implementation

```
    TrackGroupArray read_tga = db.read_tga_file(String.valueOf(myFiles.get(position).getId()),
                trackGroupArray);

    case R.id.get_file:
        trackGroupArray = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(index);
        boolean save_file = db.add_file(String.valueOf(myFiles.get(position).getId()),
                             trackGroupArray);
                if (save_file){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "saved failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

public TrackGroupArray read_tga_file(String id, TrackGroupArray tga)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TGA_FILE + " FROM "
                +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return tga;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`read_tga` always returns null even though I have checked the db and there is data saved.

[image]

Comment: If your query does find a record, you are moving to the first record in your cursor, but you never read anything from it and just return the passed in `tga`.

Comment: how could I change it to return the required query?

Comment: You have a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407043/reading-the-date-from-sqlite-in-android And the same principle applies. You have to *read from the cursor*. Just moving to the first entry won't read anything from it.  Ie you must use something like `cursor.getString()` (or whatever type your columns have).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading the date from sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407043/reading-the-date-from-sqlite-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why null could be returned.

1. The value of **tga** (the TrackGroupArray) being passed is null and thus irrespective of whether or not the row has been located then null will be returned.

or

2. The row, contrary to your expectations, has not been located and thus the result cursor from the query is empty and therefore the **moveToFirst** returns false. In which case null will be returned as per the else section.

Without actual data it is impossible to say which case. However, you can easily ascertain which case by debugging.

There are various methods that you could utilise, such as logging data and/or utilising breakpoints.

Breakpoints allow you to examine the code and values dynamically. You place a breakpoint or breakpoints.

So what you could do is to add 2 breakpoints e.g. :-

[image]

- ignore the highlighted issues.

After setting the breakpoints (just clicking where the red dots are to toggle them on/off). You run the App in Debug mode (Run/Debug, Alt+Shift_F9 or click on the little green Bug icon )
[image]

You then use the App until you get to the stage that the read_tga_file method is called. When it reaches a breakpoint the debug window will appear.

If the processing is halted at the first breakpoint then you can inspect the value of **tga**, it will be null. So you need to ensure that you don't pass a null **tga** value.

If the processing is halted at the second breakpoint then the moveToFirst method was unable to move to the first row aka no rows exist in the extracted cursor, so contrary to your expectations, the data does not match your expectations and you need to ascertain why.

Here's a [more comprehensive guide to debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/)

An alternative approach could be to write pertinent data to the Log. As you are dealing with a Cursor then you could use the DatabaseUtils **dumpCursor** method e.g.

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TGA_FILE + " FROM "
          +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
  DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor); //<<<<< ADDED for debug
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
     return tga;
  } else {
     return null;
  }
```

You can then inspect the log to see what the cursor contained.

---

**Update after comments (working example)**

You appear to be quite confused about some fundamentals.

In Java there are basically two types of variables primitives and objects. I'd suggest reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

In short primitives all have a default value and they will never be null.

Objects on the other hand, are by default null unless they are constructed/instantiated.

So `TheObject myObJectVariable;` is just saying reserve the space for an object of type **TheObject**, if that reservation is accessed then Java kindly returns the SPECIAL value of null.

If however you use `TheObject myObjectVariable = new TheObject();` then myObjectVariable is a contructed/instantiated instance of the type **TheObject** **(however member variables may well be null)**

Java caters for constructing/instantiating objects via constructors that can whilst constructing/instantiating the object supply values for the member variables. The following example shows use of the following in conjunction with saving and extracting the objects (3 of them) somewhat based upon what can be gleaned from your code.

First the object **TrackGroup** which is defined using :-

```
/*
   TrackGroup Class
 */
class TrackGroup {
   private String id;
   private String file;
   private int useCount;
   private boolean inUse = false;
   private double someValue;
   private Double otherValue;

   /* Default Constructor */
   /* if used then the object will be constructed(instantiated) with :-
         id          - will be null
         file        - will be null
         useCount    - will be 0 (as it is a primitive as opposed to an Object)
         inUse       - will be false as it is is set in the definition
         someValue   - will be 0.0 (primitive)
         otherValue  - will be null as it is an object
    */
   public TrackGroup() {} /* note if not coding other constructors there is no need to code this */

   /* This constructor requires values for all member variables to be supplied */
   /* When constructed using this Constructor the TrackGroup will have values set as passed */
   public TrackGroup(String id, String file, int useCount, boolean inUse, double someValue, Double otherValue) {
      this.id = id;
      this.file = file;
      this.useCount = useCount;
      this.inUse = inUse;
      this.someValue = someValue;
      this.otherValue = otherValue;
   }

   /* Standard Getters and Setters */
   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public String getFile() {
      return file;
   }

   public int getUseCount() {
      return useCount;
   }

   public double getSomeValue() {
      return someValue;
   }

   public Double getOtherValue() {
      return otherValue;
   }

   public boolean isInUse() {
      return inUse;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void setFile(String file) {
      this.file = file;
   }

   public void setUseCount(int useCount) {
      this.useCount = useCount;
   }

   public void setInUse(boolean inUse) {
      this.inUse = inUse;
   }

   public void setOtherValue(Double otherValue) {
      this.otherValue = otherValue;
   }

   public void setSomeValue(double someValue) {
      this.someValue = someValue;
   }
}
```

To support saving and retrieving TrackGroups in an SQLite database then the following Database helper (class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper) :-

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tga_table";
   public static final String TGA_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
   public static final String TGA_FILE = "tga_file";
   public static final String TGA_USECOUNT = "tga_usecount";
   public static final String TGA_INUSE = "tga_inuse";
   public static final String TGA_SOMEVALUE = "tga_somevalue";
   public static final String TGA_OTHERVALUE = "tga_othervalue";

   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   private static final String TABLE_CREATE_SQL =
           "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                   + TGA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
                   + "," + TGA_FILE + " TEXT"
                   + "," + TGA_USECOUNT + " INTEGER"
                   + "," + TGA_INUSE + " INTEGER"
                   + "," + TGA_SOMEVALUE + " REAL"
                   + "," + TGA_OTHERVALUE + " REAL"
                   + ");";

   private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   private static volatile DatabaseHelper instance = null;
   public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
      }
      return instance;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_SQL);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

   }

   public long insertTrackGroup(TrackGroup tga) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

      /* Note if string not a valid integer then a generated id will be used */
      try {
         cv.put(TGA_ID, Integer.parseInt(tga.getId()));
      } catch (Exception e) {}
      if (tga.getFile() != null) {
         cv.put(TGA_FILE, tga.getFile());
      }
      /* Will never be null as useCount is a primitive (int) */
      cv.put(TGA_USECOUNT,tga.getUseCount());
      cv.put(TGA_INUSE,tga.isInUse());
      cv.put(TGA_SOMEVALUE,tga.getSomeValue());
      if (tga.getOtherValue() != null) {
         cv.put(TGA_OTHERVALUE,tga.getOtherValue());
      }
      return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
   }

   @SuppressLint("Range")
   public TrackGroup getTrackGroupById(String id) {
      TrackGroup rv; /* WARNING rv is NULL as it has not been constrcuted/instantiated */
      rv = new TrackGroup(); /* Construct it NOTING that id, file and othervalue will be NULL */
      Cursor csr = db.query(
              TABLE_NAME,
              null /* ALL COLUMNS SHORTCUT */,
              "_ID=?", /* better to use TGA_ID*/
              new String[]{id},
              null,null,null
              );
      if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
         rv.setId(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_ID)));
         rv.setFile(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_FILE)));
         rv.setUseCount(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_USECOUNT)));
         rv.setInUse(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_INUSE))> 0);
         rv.setSomeValue(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_SOMEVALUE)));
         rv.setOtherValue(csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(TGA_OTHERVALUE)));
      } else {
         rv = null;
      }
      return rv;
   }
}
```

- **especially see/inspect the `getTrackGroupById` method.**

To put the above into practice/use the following code was used in an activity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TGAINFO";
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);

        /* Insert TrackGroup that has been constructed using the default constructor (not so good)*/
        long ex01_ID = dbHelper.insertTrackGroup(new TrackGroup());
        /* Insert trackGroup that has been constructed and then have appropriate values assigned */
        TrackGroup ex02 = new TrackGroup();
        ex02.setId("2222");
        ex02.setFile("EX02");
        ex02.setUseCount(2);
        ex02.setInUse(true);
        ex02.setSomeValue(2.222);
        ex02.setOtherValue(22.333);
        long ex02_ID = dbHelper.insertTrackGroup(ex02);
        /* Insert 3rd TrackGroup constructed with the custom constructor with all values supplied */
        long ex03_ID = dbHelper.insertTrackGroup(new TrackGroup("3333","EX03",3,false,3.333,33.444));

        Log.d(TAG,"Logging TGAs  extracted from the database :-");
        logTrackGroup(dbHelper.getTrackGroupById(String.valueOf(ex01_ID)));
        logTrackGroup(dbHelper.getTrackGroupById(String.valueOf(ex02_ID)));
        logTrackGroup(dbHelper.getTrackGroupById(String.valueOf(ex03_ID)));

    }

    private void logTrackGroup(TrackGroup tg) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("Found the following regarding the passed TrackGroup:-");
        if(tg != null) {
            if (tg.getId() != null) {
                sb.append("\n\tID = ").append(tg.getId());
            } else {
                sb.append("\n\t<<<<<<<<WARNING>>>>>>>> ID is NULL");
            }
            if (tg.getFile() != null) {
                sb.append("\n\tFILE = ").append(tg.getFile());
            } else {
                sb.append("\n\t<<<<<<<<WARNING>>>>>>>> FILE is NULL");
            }
            sb.append("\n\tUSE COUNT = ").append(String.valueOf(tg.getUseCount()));
            sb.append("\n\tIN USE = ").append(String.valueOf(tg.isInUse()));
            sb.append("\n\tSOME VALUE = ").append(String.valueOf(tg.getSomeValue()));
            if (tg.getOtherValue() != null) {
                sb.append("\n\t").append(String.valueOf(tg.getOtherValue()));
            } else {
                sb.append("\n\t<<<<<<<<WARNING>>>>>>>> OTHER VALUE is NULL");
            }
        } else {
            sb.append("Cannot long information about the TrackGroup as it is NULL!!!!.");
        }
        Log.d(TAG,sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- This, when run, will insert 3 rows (at least when first run) with data supplied via

1. the default constructor,
2. the default constructor followed by setting values before the insertion, and
3. the custom constructor where all values are supplied

After the data has been inserted it is then extracted according to the ID.

**Result**

When run then the log includes :-

```
D/TGAINFO: Logging TGAs  extracted from the database :-

D/TGAINFO: Found the following regarding the passed TrackGroup:-
        ID = 1
        <<<<<<<<WARNING>>>>>>>> FILE is NULL
        USE COUNT = 0
        IN USE = false
        SOME VALUE = 0.0
        0.0

D/TGAINFO: Found the following regarding the passed TrackGroup:-
        ID = 2222
        FILE = EX02
        USE COUNT = 2
        IN USE = true
        SOME VALUE = 2.222
        22.333

D/TGAINFO: Found the following regarding the passed TrackGroup:-
        ID = 3333
        FILE = EX03
        USE COUNT = 3
        IN USE = false
        SOME VALUE = 3.333
        33.444
```

- The first is an example (constructed without setting values) of how you would probably NOT proceed. The other two have values entirely as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike I checked with the breakpoints as you suggested. it is giving null in `if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return tga; tga:null 
        }` How should I change it so that it would return not null?

Comment: I have added the result above.

Comment: @aawasi you need to think about your code and why you are passing a null, or for that fact, a value that you already know the value of just to return that value. If you expect to return a TrackGroupArray that is set according to the data from the database then you want something along the lines of return new TrackGroupArray( the_values_ex extracted). If you are simple checking if the row exists, then change the type returned to  boolean and return true else false.

Comment: I want to return a TrackGroupArray that is set according to the data from the database. I have been using db but mostly its return value is an int value which can be set using cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_INDEX));. With this I am struggling how to return the tga which is not null.

Comment: @aawasi The you construct a TrackgroupArray object using a suitable constructor with values using the appropriate Cursor get???? (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) for the values.